Difference between theory and simulation of Markov chain
I was trying to simulate a Markov chain with absorptive states and to calculate average number of passages to states before absorption and I have difference between theory and simulation and I would like to know where is the problem.
Idea:
So, in my understanding  if we have a transition matrix $T$ with several absorption states and we want to calculate average number of passages from initial to other transient states, we proceed as following:

calculate fundamental matrix $F = (E-B)^{-1}$
the element $F[i,j]$ is an average number of the occupation before the absorption of the state $j$ when the initial state is $i$

Also, one can simulate Markov chain and to calculate these $F[i,j]$ from different "realizations", where I think that the average number of passages is
\begin{equation}
E\{N_B\} \approx \sum \limits_k N_B[k] f_{N_B}[k] 
\end{equation}
where $N_B$ is a number of counts of state B in the Markov chain realization, for example, it is 6 for the following chain where 'F' is an absorptive state.
$[B, C, C, B, C, C, B, C, B, C, C, B, C, C, B, C, C, D, F, F, F]$
So, I am performing a several realizations of Markov chain and can get multiple $N_B$ values and get a histogram and, equivalently,  one gets a probability of each state by normalization. So, the average value can be calculated from the previous equation using calculated probability.
Exact case:
The example I uses is as following. There are 5 states: A, B, C, D, F and the transition matrix is:
\begin{equation}
T = \begin{pmatrix}
 1   & 0   & 0   & 0   & 0   \\
 0.2 & 0   & 0.8 & 0   & 0   \\
 0   & 0.3 & 0.3 & 0.4 & 0   \\
 0   & 0   & 0.2 & 0   & 0.8 \\
 0   & 0   & 0   & 0   & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Calculation from the Fundamental matrix
With Python I get that
\begin{equation}
F \approx 
\begin{pmatrix}
1.63 & 2.1 & 0.84 \\
0.79 & 2.63 & 1.05 \\
0.16 & 0.53 & 1.21 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Simulation:
I realized simulation of Markov chain with Python, the code is below.
For example, when starting from the state C, generating 10 elements in chain (about a double of average number of steps before absorption), having realized 10000 simulations, the resulting average number of passages(which should be compared to the second row of $F$):
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
0.922 & 2.82 & 1.2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
No matter what I do and even if I increase the parameters, the differencce between theory and simulation is about 0.1-0.2. The question is: Is it normal or where am I misaken?
Code

import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the states
states = ['A', 'B', 'C','D','F']

# Define the transition matrix
P = np.array([
    [1,         0,      0,      0,      0   ],  # From A
    [0.2,       0,      0.8,    0,      0   ],  # From B
    [0,         0.3,    0.3,    0.4,    0   ],  # From C
    [0,         0,      0.2,    0,      0.8 ],  # From D
    [0,         0,      0,      0,      1   ]   # From F
])

# Function to choose the next state based on current state
def next_state(current_state, P):
    return np.random.choice(states, p=P[current_state])

# Simulate the Markov process
def simulate_markov(initial_state, P, n_steps):
    current_state = states.index(initial_state)
    state_sequence = [initial_state]
    
    for _ in range(n_steps):
        next_s = next_state(current_state, P)
        state_sequence.append(next_s)
        current_state = states.index(next_s)
    
    return state_sequence

# Simulate starting from state 'A' with 10 steps
initial_state = 'C'
print(f"initial state is {initial_state}")
n_steps = 10
#state_sequence = simulate_markov(initial_state, P, n_steps)

N_sim = 10000 # number of simulations
NB = np.zeros(N_sim,dtype =int)
NC = np.zeros(N_sim,dtype =int)
ND = np.zeros(N_sim,dtype =int)

# Counting number of passages before absorption
for k in range(0,N_sim,1):
    state_sequence = simulate_markov(initial_state, P, n_steps)
    NB[k] = state_sequence.count('B')
    NC[k] = state_sequence.count('C')
    ND[k] = state_sequence.count('D')

# getting PDF for number of passages of B and calculating average
plt.figure(num=1)
NB_counts, NB_bins, NB_PD = plt.hist(NB, bins = np.max(NB)+1, range=(0,np.max(NB)), density= True)
plt.title("counting B")

Numb_B = np.zeros(np.max(NB)+1,dtype =int)
for k in range(1,np.max(NB)+1): 
    Numb_B[k] = k 
NB_av = np.dot(Numb_B, NB_counts);


# getting PDF for number of passages of C and calculating average
plt.figure(num=2)
NC_counts, NC_bins, NC_PD = plt.hist(NC, bins = np.max(NC)+1, range=(0,np.max(NC)), density= True)
plt.title("counting C")
Numb_C = np.zeros(np.max(NC)+1,dtype =int)
for k in range(1,np.max(NC)+1): 
    Numb_C[k] = k 
NC_av = np.dot(Numb_C, NC_counts);

# getting PDF for number of passages of C and calculating average
plt.figure(num=3)
ND_counts, ND_bins, ND_PD = plt.hist(ND, bins = np.max(ND)+1, range=(0,np.max(ND)), density= True)
plt.title("counting D")

Numb_D = np.zeros(np.max(ND)+1,dtype =int)
for k in range(1,np.max(ND)+1): 
    Numb_D[k] = k 
ND_av = np.dot(Numb_D, ND_counts);

print(f"average number of B passages before absorption: {NB_av}")
print(f"average number of C passages before absorption: {NC_av}")
print(f"average number of D passages before absorption: {ND_av}")

#%% Comparing to direct fundamental matrix calculation

B = np.array([
    [   0,      0.8,    0   ],  # From B
    [   0.3,    0.3,    0.4 ],  # From C
    [   0,      0.2,    0   ],  # From D
])

Fund = np.linalg.inv(np.identity(3) - B)

print(f"The fundamental matrix:\n{Fund}")
```


My simulation, implemented in Maple, yields values which agree, to two decimal places, with the expected values.

@quasi, do you have the same simulation parameters as me, number of points of chain and number of realisations? I have 10 steps in each chain and 10000 chains in total.

I used $10^2$ steps and $10^6$ chains.

I wonder do we need that much states since the average number of states before absorbtion is about 4.5 ? how much states are really need?

With $10$ steps and $10^4$ chains, the values from my simulation agree with the expected values to only one decimal place (but still a lot more accurate than your results).

Anyway, I have made the same number of chains and steps and I have the same problem as before

Then the error is in your python code.

0.84, 2.7, 1.18, error of about 0.6 -0.13

It seems that the error is in the histogram definition, I take one more point for bins that I should. After correcting that, the precision is much better

bins = np.max(NC)+1 instead of bins = np.max(NC)

and the same for other states  B and D

thank you for checking with Maple

Here's a Python rewrite of my Maple simulation . . .
import numpy as np
from random import random

def sim(Q,s0,K,T):
   n=Q.shape[0]
   v=np.zeros(n,dtype=np.int64)
   for t in range(0,T):
      s,k=s0,0
      while True:
         v[s]+=1
         if k>=K: break
         k+=1
         P,r,ok=0,random(),False
         for s1 in range(0,n):
            P+=Q[s,s1]
            if r<P: s=s1; ok=True; break
         if not ok: break
   print(v/T)

Q=np.array([[0,.8,0],[.3,.3,.4],[0,.2,0]])
sim(Q,1,100,1000000)

which yields the output: [0.791614 2.631846 1.051496]

Python syntax: Expected an indented block after "while True:" statement.

@gpmath: Thanks. Now fixed.

Set $n_{\text{steps}}=100$ in your source code:
# Compute mean values
NB_av = NB.mean()
NC_av = NC.mean()
ND_av = ND.mean()

Then you will get the expected values, i.e.
initial state is C
average number of B passages before absorption: 0.7815
average number of C passages before absorption: 2.6177
average number of D passages before absorption: 1.0533

If you want to improve simulation accuracy, increase $N_{\text{sim}}$, i.e. $N_{\text{sim}}=100000$

I have tryed that, also, there is mistake in the definition of PDF. When calculating histogram I make to many bins for NB etc, when corrected precision is better. It is clear that if PDF is not well defined, the average value will move. As observed here
